# Application Insights with invalid instrumentation key - how to handle as no error is thrown

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

Is there a way to capture an error when when an invalid instrumentation key is used when tracing messages to Application Insights?

I'm programmatically specifying an instrumentation key like below but no exception is thrown.
 I'm trying to build a Logging WebApi that will return a success or failure dependent on whether the message was successfully logged to Application Insights?

```
TelemetryConfiguration config = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
config.InstrumentationKey = "ABC";
client.TrackTrace("Test"),SeverityLevel.Information);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement your own channel that implements [ITelemetryChannel](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/develop/src/Core/Managed/Shared/Channel/ITelemetryChannel.cs), and handle exceptions as you want.

Here's a naive example:

```
public class SynchronousTelemetryChannel : ITelemetryChannel
{
    private const string ContentType = "application/x-json-stream";
    private readonly List<ITelemetry> _items;
    private object _lock = new object();
    public bool? DeveloperMode { get; set; }
    public string EndpointAddress { get; set; }

    public SynchronousTelemetryChannel()
    {
        _items = new List<ITelemetry>();
        EndpointAddress = "https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track";
    }

    public void Send(ITelemetry item)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            _items.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public void Flush()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] data = JsonSerializer.Serialize(_items);
                new Transmission(new Uri(EndpointAddress), data, ContentType, JsonSerializer.CompressionType).SendAsync().Wait();
                _items.Clear();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Do whatever you want.
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Then, initialize the configuration with your channel via code or [configuration file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-configuration-with-applicationinsights-config):

```
        TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryChannel = new SynchronousTelemetryChannel();
```